# How to set side bar between two div and it should fit in the any browser window based on resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having two grid one div is header another one is footer between the two grid, I am using sidebar in left side.

Here is my JavaScript code

```
function resize()
{
    var heights = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementById("left").style.height = heights + "px";
}
resize();
window.onresize = function() {
    resize();
};
```

I want to show this full content with in the page without show any browser scroll bar.

Here is my demo

[Click here to see my demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/cqzpvsue/)

Comment: why should i use snippet

Answer (score 0):

**Using Jquery:**

You take the browser screen height

```
$(window).height()
```

& then reduce the height of header & footer

```
$(window).height() - $('header').outerHeight() - $('footer').outerHeight()
```

**Using JS**

```
window.innerWidth - document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight - document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
```

Instead of offsetHeight you can also use clientHeight. Difference is:

`clientHeight` includes padding.

`offsetHeight` includes padding, scrollBar and borders.

**Updated**

Update your `function resize()` as:

```
document.getElementById('inner').style.maxHeight = window.innerWidth - document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight - document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
```

Comment: @Vinoth Updated the answer

Comment: if i am adding more option in sidebar it wll going down. my requirement is if the side bar exceeds the screen size it should show vertical scroll (overflow -y)

Comment: your <h1> element inside footer is having margin. Set the top & bottom margin as 0.

Comment: Firstly, you need to modify your "function resize()" with the provided JS answer for getting the height for your "inner" div.
Second, your should always use the [reset css](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) to avoid browser default styles.

Comment: that is i am asking how to get the inner div height for using function resize

Comment: If i am not using header and footer means the side working correctly. ex: if the option exceeds based on screen size it will show the scroll bar. after i am using header and footer it still matain the same height.

Comment: document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight gives you height

Comment: if i am adding too option in side bar, it is not showing any vertical scroll bar on sidebar. just see this https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/cqzpvsue/10/

Comment: You need to set max-height then

Comment: That is i am asking how to set max-height for side bar.

Comment: document.getElementById('header').style.maxHeight = "100px";

Comment: Have updated my answer. Check & accept the answer if that works fine for you.

Comment: I dont want to customize the height. it should set height depends on betwen two div

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure CSS: there are a few ways to determine the behavior of CSS to adjust to screen size. I think that a good method for this is to use the viewport units: `vw` and `vh`, this will let you achieve responsive design easily...

**vw** stands for "viewport width" and **vh** is for "viewport height". and,
you can use it with CSS like in this example:

```
div {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}
```

[This guide](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/) may be helpful to understand this method better...

You can also set *px* for pixels and other [CSS sizing units](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) instead of *%* and also use **vmin** and **vmax** for minimum and maximum size adjustment, or just use min-height/width like in this example:

```
.sidebar {
min-width: 30%;
min-height: 30%;
}
```

Another more modern way is to do it with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)...

Comment: not working..... can u check my code is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/cqzpvsue/3/